# Como aprovar posts de autores no Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Estou tendo um "plobleminha".

Hoje me deparei com a necessidade de adicionar uma função que não é nativa no **Wordpress**.

É o seguinte:

> Esse site tem vários autores, eu gostaria que sempre que um `Autor` publicar um post, ele não apareça de imediato no site, antes o post tem que passar por aprovação, então só depois que um `Editor` ou `Administrador` aprovar o post que ele será exibido para todos os visitantes.

Já instalei vários `plugins` e até agora nenhum me satisfez.

Gostaria de algo simples, só que quando um autor publicar o post ele seja enviado para aprovação, seja enviado uma notificação para `Painel` dos Editores ou Administradores para então poder aprová-lo.

Alguém conhece um `Plugin` que realmente funcione? Ou conhece outra solução?

Answer (score 9):

Uma forma de fazer isso sem recorrer a plugins, é despromover os Autores para Colaboradores. Assim, a opção que lhes aparece é “Submeter para revisão” em vez de “Publicar”.

Para mudar o perfil: Utilizadores> Seleccionar Utilizador> Editar>Alterar perfil(para Colaborador)

Vista do Colaborador
[image: Painel do Colaborador]

Vista do Admin
[image: Painel do Administrador]

Artigos>Pendentes> Seleccione o artigo> Publicar

Mais info, veja resumo de funcoes em http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es_e_Capacidades

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Só que assim não funciona, pois assim a pessoa não pode fazer uploads e nem moderar os comentários nos seus posts. Já resolvi aqui usando o plugin `User Role Editor`, aí eu fiz com que os `Autores` não tivessem permissão para postar, assim quando ele criar um post é enviado para revisão igual o do Colaborador. No momento foi a melhor solução que encontrei. :D Mas muito obrigado por tentar ajudar! Abraço!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes obrigado por compartilhar o plugin, parece util. Nao prestei atençao a outras limitaçoes dos colaboradores :-)

Answer (score 1):

Num dos meus sites, uso uma função que cria um cargo personalizado. Você pode colocar os "redatores" nele e assim terão as permissões que você determinar.

Na *functions*:

```
// Cria cargo Colaborador Top, que só não pode excluir posts
add_role('colaboradortop', 'Colaborador Top', array(
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false,
    'edit_published_posts' => true,
    'publish_posts' => false, // só pode salvar rascunhos
    'edit_files' => true,
    'read' => true,
    'upload_files' => true //pode enviar arquivos
));
```

Veja todas as funções e capacidade no [Codex do Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es_e_Capacidades).

Comment: **Caveat:** Como `add_role` faz uma alteração direta no BD, a função retorna cedo e não altera nada se o nome (ex. "colaboradortop") já existe no banco. Isso torna impossível modificar as capabilities apenas modificando o array da função, como se fossem parâmetros normais definidos no carregamento do tema. É aconselhável usar essa função somente nos hooks que rodam na ativação do tema ou plugin, usando também remove_role na desativação.